# Add element from list to dictionary and increase value

Tags: python

I have dictionary and a list. List only contains items, dictionary contains items and how many of a given item do I have. What I'm trying to do is to iterate through a dict and list, and if the key in a dict is the same as item in a list I only want to update its value by 1 but if there are no the same items I want to add the item form list to dict and set its value to 1.

```
stock = {apple: 1, banana: 4, orange: 10}
delivery = [apple, apple, grapefruit]

    for k, v in stock.items():
        for item in delivery:
            if item == stock[k]:
                stock[v] += 1
        else:
            stock.update({item:1})
```

Output should look sth like this:

```
stock = {apple: 3, banana: 4, orange: 10, grapefruit: 1}
```

However I'm getting message: dictionary changed size during iteration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't change `dict` or `list` while iterating over it. You can write your code like:

```
stock = {'apple': 1, 'banana': 4, 'orange': 10}
delivery = ['apple', 'apple', 'grapefruit']

for item in delivery:
    if item in stock:
        stock[item] +=1
    else:
        stock[item] = 1

print(stock)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use `Counter` from `collections` which does exactly what you want.

```
from collections import Counter
stock = Counter({'apple': 1, 'banana': 4, 'orange': 10})
delivery = ['apple', 'apple', 'grapefruit']
stock.update(delivery)
```

Comment: It is in the `collections` module.

Comment: Why convert back to `dict`? `Counter` is a subclass of `dict` so this conversion is rarely required.

Comment: Because `Counter` returns a `Counter`object and not a `dict`as required.

Comment: Does it make output like ` {apple: 3, banana: 4, orange: 10, grapefruit: 1}` ?  I am getting `{'apple': 2, 'grapefruit': 1}` as output.

Comment: This code creates a **new** dict, doesn't update the existing one, as required by the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict.get()`:

```
stock = {'apple': 1, 'banana': 4, 'orange': 10}
delivery = ['apple', 'apple', 'grapefruit']

for d in delivery:
    stock[d] = stock.get(d, 0) + 1

print(stock)
```

Output:

```
{'apple': 3, 'banana': 4, 'orange': 10, 'grapefruit': 1}
```

Comment: Short and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reverse the order of enumeration and iterate over the list, adding items to the dict or increasing their value by one, as appropriate:

```
for item in delivery:
    if item in stock:
        stock[item] += 1
    else:
        stock[item] = 1
```

(note you can also use defaultdict(int) for your 'stock' dict object, so you don't even need the if/else and can do just:

```
for item in delivery:
    stock[item] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best idea in this case will be to use a *Counter* collection instead of a standard dict (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)
Check out the basic example given there:

```
# Tally occurrences of words in a list
cnt = Counter()
for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
    cnt[word] += 1
```

When using the standard dict you can loop over the list and along the following lines:

```
for v in delivery:
    try:
        stock[v] += 1
    except KeyError:
        stock[v] = 1
```

Alternatively you can use the *get * method of the dict and test for None.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.counter` for this purpose

```
from collections import Counter
stock = Counter({'apple': 1, 'banana': 4, 'orange': 10})
delivery = ['apple', 'apple', 'grapefruit']
stock.update(delivery)

stock
# Counter({'orange': 10, 'banana': 4, 'apple': 3, 'grapefruit': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible like this:

```
stock = {'apple': 1, 'banana': 4, 'orange': 10}
delivery = ['apple', 'apple', 'grapefruit']

stock.update({item: delivery.count(item) + stock.get(item,0) 
               for item in set(delivery)}) 

print(stock)
# {'apple': 3, 'banana': 4, 'orange': 10, 'grapefruit': 1})
```